# Task continuations always run even when specifying TaskContinuationOptions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I want to run some code when an async task completes successfully.

From reading documentation and examples on the web, I thought I could use `Task.ContinueWith` and specify `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion`.

However, this doesn't behave as I expected.

The following code is a console program, created in Visual Studio 2012, .Net 4.5:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskContinueTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jobTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });

            jobTask.ContinueWith((task, options) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Completed handler. Task status is {0}", task.Status);
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

            jobTask.ContinueWith((task, options) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Faulted handler. Task status is {0}", task.Status);
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

when run, I get the output:

```
Completed handler. Task status is RanToCompletion
Faulted handler. Task status is RanToCompletion
```

which is very surprising (at least to me). Why are both continuations scheduled?

I get the same behavior if I throw an exception in `jobTask`, but the output is now:

```
Completed handler. Task status is Faulted
Faulted handler. Task status is Faulted
```

So the framework clearly knows the status of the task, but why are both continuations still scheduled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're accidentally calling [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139097.aspx)

```
public Task ContinueWith(
    Action<Task, Object> continuationAction,
    Object state
)
```

What you want is [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321576.aspx):

```
public Task ContinueWith(
    Action<Task> continuationAction,
    TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions
)
```

You just need to change your lambda expressions to use a single parameter:

```
Task.ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine(...),
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

Comment: Is it different in .NET 4.5? Because in .NET 4.0 the OP's code gives on (2) line(s) `jobTask.ContinueWith((task, options) =>` the compilation  error `Delegate 'System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' does not take 2 arguments`!