# Task Inside Loop

Tags: c#, task

I have a windows service with a thread that runs every 2 minutes.

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        repNeg.willExecuteLoopWithTasks(param1, param2, param3);
        Thread.Sleep(20000);
    }
```

Inside this I have a loop with tasks:

```
foreach (RepModel repModelo in listaRep)
{
    Task t = new Task(() => { this.coletaFunc(repModelo.EndIp, user, tipoFilial); });
    t.Start();
}
```

But I think this implementation is wrong. I need to only run one task for every element in the list, 
and, when a specific task finishes, wait a minute and start again.

M8's I need to say i have 2 situations here.

1 - I can't wait all Task Finish. Because some task can take more then 2 hours to finish and another can take only 27 seconds.

2 -  My List of tasks can change. Thats why i got a Thread. Every 2 minutes My thread get a list of Tasks to execute and then start a loop.

But sometimes my Task not Finished yet and another Thread Start Again and then strange things show in my log.
I tryed to use a Dictionry to solve my problem but after some time of execution, sometimes takes days, my log show:

"System.IndexOutOfRangeException"

Comment: you don't need task, just call that function.

Comment: I think you should be looking at using the Timer Class. Your implementation is not good. I would research Asynchronous Methods. You don't want to block threads.

Comment: @Derek is it a blocked thread if it is doing the intended work?

Comment: Side note:  `Thread.Sleep(20000)` will sleep for _20 seconds_, not _2 minutes_.

Comment: using Thread.Sleep is not good practice imo, What your doing is taking a thread from the threadpool, and have it do nothing for 2 minutes. thats bad practice, as it could be back in the threadppol used as a resource for something else. @DStanley

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do...

Create a new class that stores the following (as properties):

- a `RepModel` ID (something unique)
- a `DateTime` for the last time ran
- a `int` for the frequency the task should run in seconds
- a `bool` to determine if the task is in progress or not

Then you need a global list of the class somewhere, say called "JobList".

Your main app should have a Timer, which runs every couple of minutes. The job of this timer is to check for new `RepModel` (assume these can change over time, i.e a database list). When this ticks, is loops the list and adds any new ones (different ID) to `JobList`. You may also want to remove any that are no longer required (i.e. removed from DB list).

Then you have a second timer, this runs every second. It's job is to check all items in the `JobList` and compare the last run time with the current time (and ensure they are not already in progress). If the duration has lapped, then kick off the task. Once the task is complete, update the last run time so it can work next time, ensuring to change the "in progress" flag as you go.

This is all theory and you will need to give it a try yourself, but I think it covers what you are actually trying to achieve.

---

Some sample code (may or may not compile/work):

```
class Job
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastRun { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
    public bool InProgress { get; set; }
}

List<Job> JobList = new List<Job>();

// Every 2 minutes (or whatever).
void timerMain_Tick()
{
    foreach (RepModel repModelo in listaRep)
    {
        if(!JobList.Any(x => x.ID == repModelo.ID)
        {
            JobList.Add(new Job(){ ID = repModel.ID, Frequency = 120 });
        }
    }
}

// Every 10 seconds (or whatever).
void timerTask_Tick()
{
    foreach(var job in JobList.Where(x => !x.InProgress && (x.LastRun == null || DateTime.Compare(x.LastRun.AddSeconds(x.Duration), DateTime.Now) < 0))
    {
        Task t = new Task(() => { 
            // Do task.
        }).ContinueWith(task => {
            job.LastRun = DateTime.Now;
            job.InProgress = false;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());;
        job.InProgress = true;
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Musefan, What will happen if one or more tasks not finished yet and MainTick start?

Comment: Not much, MainTick just keeps the list of tasks that should be processed up to date. If a big task has started running, then it will continue uneffected. It won't get run again until at least after it has finished (that is what `InProgress` is for)

Comment: The only bit I am not really sure about is the `ContinueWith` bit that updates the LastRun and InProgress. Not sure if that `job` object will still be available/relevant... it's too much for me to set up a test for this I'm afraid

Comment: What about Error 18 Delegate 'System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' does not take 0 arguments this error? :(

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414198/task-continuations-always-run-even-when-specifying-taskcontinuationoptions) I updated my code

Comment: Now Show this erros The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.

Comment: and "Start may not be called on a continuation task".

Comment: Like I said, the code is concept. I don't have time or effort to write it properly for you. Google the errors, they should be pretty obvious

Answer (score 0):

So what you really need here is a class that has two operations, it needs to be able to start processing one of your models, and it needs to be able to end processing of one of your models.  Separating it from the list will make this easier.

When you start processing a model you'll want to create a `CancellationTokenSource` to associate with it so that you can stop processing it later.  Processing it, in your case, means having a loop, while not cancelled, that runs an operation and then waits a while.  Ending the operation is as easy as cancelling the token source.

```
public class Foo
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<RepModel, CancellationTokenSource> tokenLookup =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<RepModel, CancellationTokenSource>();
    public async Task Start(RepModel model)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        tokenLookup[model] = cts;
        while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => model.DoWork());
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        }
    }

    public void End(RepModel model)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts;
        if (tokenLookup.TryRemove(model, out cts))
            cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, look nice, but cant imagine it runing inside my loop :(. To complex for me understand this!

Comment: @PauloJardim What don't you understand?  You realize that using this is as simple as calling `Start` when you want to start running a model and `End` whenever you want to stop.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: where my loop go in this sample? You understand shuld be a infinite loop?

Comment: @PauloJardim The loop is already there.  When you call `Start` it will perform the operation on the model in a loop until `Stop` is called.

Comment: But for every Model i will need pass diferent's param's. I Have a

Comment: @PauloJardim Then add those parameters to `Start` and pass them in.

Comment: still cant implement this. maybe i didint understand where my cond enter in here!

Comment: @PauloJardim When you want to start running the code for a model, you call `Start` and pass in the model.  When you want to stop running the code for that model, you call `End` on it.  Change `DoWork` to do whatever work you have to do for the model, and that's that.

Comment: but await Task.Run(() => model.DoWork()); this code dont work. Sorry but dont know much about work with Task.

Comment: @PauloJardim You'll need to change `DoWork` to do whatever work you want your model to do.

Comment: @PauloJardim So then what's the problem?  `Task.Run` runs a method in another thread, and `await` schedules the remainder of the method to be a continuation of the task that is awaited, or put another wait, it waits asynchronously.

Comment: @PauloJardim That's an entirely useless statement on its own.  At a minimum, you'd need to provide a compiler error.  That said, I've compiled the code myself and it compiles just fine.

Comment: "Error 2 ; expected " just this. after "await Task.Run" and "await Task.Delay"

Comment: @PauloJardim The use of `await` requires C# 5.0.

Comment: Thats Why...suposed to be...LOL

Answer (score -1):

If you are using framework `4.0` and more, you may try to benefit from

[Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Executes a foreach operation in which iterations may run in parallel.

Parallel code may look like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(listaRep , repModelo => {
     this.coletaFunc(repModelo.EndIp, user, tipoFilial);

});
```

This will run on multiple cores (if that is possible), and you don't need some specific task sceduler, as your code will wait until all parallel tasks inside parallel loop are finished. And after you can call recursively the same function, if condition was met.

Comment: Tigran, I can't wait all task finish. Please I edited my question

Comment: @PauloJardim: so what should happen if one task is not finshed yet, and another need to be start ?

Comment: Tigran, should jump this one only.

Comment: but that is not a problem of parallel engine itself, but, a this point, the problem is in Task Scehduler, who injects into the Queue a job that not yet finished... is any given job can be uniquely identified and queried for its state of execution ?

Comment: The task is to conect to a spec specific hardware and colect some informartion about then and then save on DB. But some of this machines take a long to recovery all information. But can't wait all finished. i need this information as soo as possible

Comment: yes,  I get the list of tasks from DB, each one hardware has a COD and IP

Comment: so you push task in the queue and run tasks for each of them, every task when completes removed from the queue its object. the sceduler , when time came to push new task, checks the content of the queue. and push inside only those tasks, that are not present, hence finished. does this make sense ?

Comment: i will try this Tigram. Very Tanks!